# SearchView is not displayed on toolbar with nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, oncreate, oncreateoptionsmenu

I must have read almost all the question and answers related to this, but still cannot get it to work. Below is the rough sketch of how the app looks.
[image]
Adding code below to give structure of the layout and where I might be doing wrong.

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

bottom_nav_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/liquor_type_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
           />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
          />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
          />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
           />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
           />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/price_list_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

For each of tab item, I have used a common fragment which will have different data in recyclerView.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.nandu.oru10ml.price_list.CommonPriceFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // MenuInflater inflater = getS
    Log.d("Activity Options", "inside onCreateOptionsMenu ");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_item, menu);

    return true;
}
```

BottomNavFragment.java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment onCreate", "inside onCreate ");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Fragment Options", "inside onCreateOptionsMenu ");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_item, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

CommonFragment.java

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Fragment onCreate", "inside onCreate ");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d("Fragment Options", "inside onCreateOptionsMenu ");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_item, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

and finally, search_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search for Brand"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView">
</item>
</menu>
```

The reason why it is not working would also help me understand the root cause.

This SearhView is applicable to 2 of the bottom nav Fragment and all of the nested Fragments inside, to search Recyclerview present in each of it.

Comment: Do the menu options change at all as you go to the different fragments?

I never saw anything in Main activity of setting the toolbar as the supportActionBar

Comment: It's only search, no other menu options.

Comment: Gotcha, then it definitely sounds like you should add a setSupportActionBar(toolbar) to your mainactivity and that will make the options menu code run

Comment: Okay, let me try tgat and see.
Is everything else as it should be?

Comment: Could you give bit more detail? I tried it onCreate method, but setSupportActionBar() doesn't take any arguments. Also, toolbar is in fragment.

Comment: setSupportActionBar should take the argument as a toolbar. So what you should do is inside your fragment call ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: The problem was with wrong import and it's working!!!!
But there are three search button now and it disappears after I click on it to type!

Comment: If you add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setSupportActionBar should take the argument as a toolbar. So what you should do is, inside your fragment call

`((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`